# Error when loading JavascriptConfiguration.xml

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to use HtmlUnit for the first time.
Working in Eclipse for EE.
I have the jar files in my buildpath.
The project compiles but when run it give the runtime error:

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration loadConfiguration
SEVERE: Error when loading JavascriptConfiguration.xml

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getConfigurationFileAsReader(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:256)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.loadConfiguration(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:180)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:142)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:237)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.(JavaScriptEngine.java:117)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(WebClient.java:215)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.(WebClient.java:189)

have found some posts saying where to get that file and where to put it but nothing helped.
anybody know?
thanks